# How to find highest level descendants with a given name

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am looking for a way to find the first result level in a XML tree using linq. The XML I have is like the following:

```
<column>
    <row>
        <object/>
        <column column-id="1" column-name="abc">
            <row>
                <column>
                    <row>
                        <column column-id="2" column-name="abc"/>
                    </row>
                </column>
            </row>
        </column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column column-id="3" column-name="abc">
            <row>
                <column/>
            </row>
        </column>
    </row>
</column>
```

Now I want to get all the first level `columns` where the column-name is `abc`. So the result should be:

```
<column column-id="1" column-name="abc">...</column>
<column column-id="3" column-name="abc">...</column>
```

I have tried already the following code:

```
layout.Descendants("column")
      .Where(x => x.Attribute("column-name").Value.Equals("abc") && !x.Ancestors("column").Any());
```

This works fine when the `XElement layout` being searched is not named `"column"` and is not nested inside any container elements named `"column"`.  But my `XElement` does, in fact, belong inside a document whose root element is named `"column"`, so the `x.Ancestors("column").Any()` expression wrongly filters out all matches.  I.e. the problem can be reproduced using the XML string above by initializing `layout` as follows:

```
var layout = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
```

I want to keep the relation in the variable because of changes I have to make later on.

Is there maybe a way limit the ancestors selector?

Comment: Please provide the example where your solution doesn't work. It will be helpful.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria - actually the XML in the question does reproduce the problem, it just wasn't clear from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't know in advance the precise depth of the elements for which you are querying, what you want to do is to descend the element hierarchy underneath a specified element, and return the *topmost* elements that match a given condition, in this case having the name `"column"`.

As a quick-and-dirty way to do this, you can only check for ancestors of the candidate matched column that are still descendants of `layout` by using [`TakeWhile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var matches = layout
    .Descendants("column")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("column-name") == "abc" && !x.Ancestors().TakeWhile(a => a != layout).Any(a => a.Name == "column"));
```

A more performant, general solution would be to introduce an extension method on `XElement` that enumerates through all descendants of the given element, returning the topmost elements that match a given predicate.  This would be generally useful e.g. in cases where one wants to query for descendants that are going to be near the top of a deep XML hierarchy, as it avoids descending unnecessarily into matched nodes:

```
public static partial class XElementExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerates through all descendants of the given element, returning the topmost elements that match the given predicate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root"></param>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> DescendantsUntil(this XElement root, Func<XElement, bool> predicate, bool includeSelf = false)
    {
        if (predicate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return GetDescendantsUntil(root, predicate, includeSelf);
    }

    static IEnumerable<XElement> GetDescendantsUntil(XElement root, Func<XElement, bool> predicate, bool includeSelf)
    {
        if (root == null)
            yield break;
        if (includeSelf && predicate(root))
        {
            yield return root;
            yield break;
        }
        var current = root.FirstChild<XElement>();
        while (current != null)
        {
            var isMatch = predicate(current);
            if (isMatch)
                yield return current;

            // If not a match, get the first child of the current element.
            XElement next = (isMatch ? null : current.FirstChild<XElement>());

            if (next == null)
                // If no first child, get the next sibling of the current element.
                next = current.NextSibling<XElement>();

            // If no more siblings, crawl up the list of parents until hitting the root, getting the next sibling of the lowest parent that has more siblings.
            if (next == null)
            {
                for (var parent = current.Parent as XElement; parent != null && parent != root && next == null; parent = parent.Parent as XElement)
                {
                    next = parent.NextSibling<XElement>();
                }
            }

            current = next;
        }
    }

    public static TNode FirstChild<TNode>(this XNode node) where TNode : XNode
    {
        var container = node as XContainer;
        if (container == null)
            return null;
        return container.FirstNode.NextSibling<TNode>(true);
    }

    public static TNode NextSibling<TNode>(this XNode node) where TNode : XNode
    {
        return node.NextSibling<TNode>(false);
    }

    public static TNode NextSibling<TNode>(this XNode node, bool includeSelf) where TNode : XNode
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        for (node = (includeSelf ? node : node.NextNode); node != null; node = node.NextNode)
        {
            var nextTNode = node as TNode;
            if (nextTNode != null)
                return nextTNode;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var matches = layout
    .DescendantsUntil(x => x.Name == "column")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("column-name") == "abc");
```

The extension method should be reasonably performant as it avoids recursion and complex nested linq queries.

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2LXuw) showing both options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. The use of `DescendantsUntil` did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to state the question is that you want your predicate to include the distance from the document root.

Here is a function that does that:

```
static int DistanceToRoot(XElement elem, XElement root)
{
    var dist = 0;

    var curr = elem;

    while(curr != root)
    {
        dist++;
        curr = curr.Parent;
    }

    return dist;
}
```

And you use it like so (based on your example, the distance that we want is **2**):

```
var columns = from column in xml.Descendants("column")
              where 
                  DistanceToRoot(column, xml.Root) == 2  &&
                  column.Attribute("column-name").Value == "abc"
              select column;


 foreach(var abc in xyzs)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(abc);
     Console.Write("Distance is: ");
     Console.WriteLine(DistanceToRoot(abc, xml.Root));
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Which results in:

```
<column column-id="1" column-name="abc">
  <row>
    <column>
      <row>
        <column column-id="2" column-name="abc" />
      </row>
    </column>
  </row>
</column>
Distance is: 2

<column column-id="3" column-name="abc">
  <row>
    <column />
  </row>
</column>
Distance is: 2
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ICU89821)**.