# C# parsing an xml document to find <w:p> tag with paraId equal to some value

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, word-automation

I am using the following code to parse the xml of word document but I am unable to figure out how to do the LINQ query to find the node I need. Basically I have a table so there is a <w:tr> tags and I want to zone in on the one with a paraId equal to "12345" and I need to get the <w:p> tags inside of this <w:tr> node. My code so far is as follows:

```
                    XDocument xdc = XDocument.Parse(docText);
                    var arrNames = xdc.Root
                    .Descendants("w:tr")
                    .Select(e => e.Attribute("w14:paraId")).ToArray();
```

I am not very familiar with LINQ or XML so this is a bit tricky for me. The structure of the xml is pretty much as follows:

```
       <w:tr w:rsidRPr="00DC3742" w:rsidR="009336A8" w:rsidTr="1FCAB362" w14:paraId="570B1706" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:tc>
           <w:tcPr>
              <w:tcW w:w="10728" w:type="dxa" />
              <w:tcBorders>
                 <w:top w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="4" w:space="0" />
                 <w:left w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="4" w:space="0" />
                 <w:bottom w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="4" w:space="0" />
                 <w:right w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="4" w:space="0" />
              </w:tcBorders>
              <w:tcMar />
           </w:tcPr>
           <w:p w:rsidRPr="00896505" w:rsidR="009336A8" w:rsidP="1FCAB362" w:rsidRDefault="009336A8" w14:paraId="3574A5D8" w14:textId="5A2EB300">
              <w:pPr>
                 <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
                 <w:numPr>
                    <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
                    <w:numId w:val="10" />
                 </w:numPr>
                 <w:spacing w:after="0" />
                 <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                    <w:b w:val="1" />
                    <w:bCs w:val="1" />
                 </w:rPr>
              </w:pPr>
              <w:r w:rsidRPr="1FCAB362" w:rsidR="03C18AEE">
                 <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                    <w:b w:val="1" />
                    <w:bCs w:val="1" />
                 </w:rPr>
                 <w:t>This actually worked! Take 2</w:t>
              </w:r>
           </w:p>
        </w:tc>
     </w:tr>
```

So I am basically just trying to target the <w:p> tags within the table row and store them as an array or just serialize them to a string.

Comment: You code won't work because the names spaces are defined by URL and you need to search by the namespaces.

Comment: How would I do that? Thanks for heads up.

Comment: I parsed another xml this morning.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002535/descendantsuntil-in-case-of-nested-elements/76004804#76004804  Instead of getting Default namespace you would need to use GetNamespaceOfPrefix()

Comment: Struggling to understand you solution there.

Comment: Compare code with the actual XML input.  I thought I made code easy to understand by parsing in sections in each class.

Comment: So you are looping through each node then. Is there not a easier LINQ solution to search ?

Comment: The only two method I use is Elements() and Descendants().  The example was a tree structure and I couldn't use Descendants() because I wanted to parse one branch at a time.  The sample had a default namespace (no prefix) that I had to use throughout the file.  You have a prefix 'w' that you need to define for your code to work.

Comment: Who would have thought getting some chunks of writing from a word doc would be so complex lol.

Comment: There is very little text, mostly formatting.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I could answer -just copy and paste. If  you want somthing else pls show us the code you have tried so far

Comment: how is it not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(docText);
var root = xDoc.Root;

var w = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w");
var w14 = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w14");

var xRow = root.Descendants(w + "tr").FirstOrDefault(
    tr => tr.Attribute(w14 + "paraId")?.Value == "12345");

if (xRow != null)
{
    var xPars = xRow.Descendants(w + "p").ToArray();
    // TODO, use "w:p" elements...
}
```

Comment: Your code does exactly what i wanted and gets the <w:p> tags inside so this is the correct answer. I am somewhat confused though how namespace and the prefixes are related. So Tr is considered an attrinbute and w is considered the namespace?

Comment: @IrishRedneck the "w" part in the <w:tr> and in <w:p> is the namespace. Also, the "w14:paraId" attribute has a different namespace, the "w14". These namespaces are defined at the beginning of the "document.xml" file.

Comment: Gotcha! If you were trying to take these parsed nodes and replace in the other word doc xml would you just serialize and do a string.replace()?

Comment: @IrishRedneck on each item in "xPars" array (let's call it "xPar") I would use "xPar.ReplaceWith" method.