# How to exclude nested XML elements when using C# XElement and LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document I am trying to parse, with nested elements with the same name.  I need to treat these differently to their parent node, and maintain a child\parent relationship.  However when I iterate the collection using Descendants("node"), In my parent nodes, I get both the parent and child nodes, as they have the same element name.

My XML:

```
<config>
    <nodes>
        <node>
            <parentthings>
            </parentthings>
            <node>
                <childthings>
                </childthings>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node>
            <parentthings>
            </parentthings>
        </node>
    </nodes>
</config>
```

Is there a way to prevent this occurring in my parser?

Comment: You could use `XElementExtensions.DescendantsUntil()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46016931/3744182) to [How to find highest level descendants with a given name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46007738/3744182).  Does that answer your question?